# how to login a user using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

In my computer i have two user(tiger,jenk)
now i want to create a shell script for login user "jenk" from  user "tiger" 
i m try this code

```
[tiger@pagaltiger mytask]$ echo -e "IncorrectPassword\n" | su jenk
Password: su: Authentication failure
echo -e "CorrectPassword" | su jenk
[tiger@pagaltiger mytask]$
```

then i am again login as  a tiger user what's going wrong with me

**I m not want to use expect**

Comment: what is unclear for you in this question.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best best is to set up a secure shell daemon on the system (if it's not already running) and use paswordless keypair authentication.  Presuming that `sshd` is already in place, you can log in as `tiger` and run the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id jenk@localhost
```

After that, `tiger` will be able to run a command as `jenk` with the following syntax:

```
ssh jenk@localhost '(some command here)'
```

For example:

```
tiger@hostname $ ssh jenk@localhost 'whoami'
jenk
tiger@hostname $
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run that command *in a pipe*, it spawns a new process rather than running the command in the current shell.  The new shell switches to the user `jenk`, but when that shell exits (since it didn't have anything else to do), your original shell which spawned that shell is still logged in as you.

If you run the command in a script, it will be run in a subshell regardless of whether it's in a pipeline or not.

(My advice is just type `su jenk` and then type in the password; it's simpler that way.)

Comment: but i want to login using shell script.